# How to get all referenced pages where i used my custom lightning component?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

Is there any way to get all referenced pages where i used my custom lightning component using salesforce api.

Example: I created a **custom lightning component page** 'Reminder' and used into **custom tab** view in Record Page or replace existing record view using **Edit Page** option.

I need to find all page information where my custom lightning component referenced.

Please share if any helpful SOQL query or rest api exist for that .

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I use Linux, so I like to pull down the metadata definitions and then grep through them.

You would first need to retrieve the relevant metadata with a metadata api retrieve call using your tool of choice. Here's a sample package manifest for performing a retrieval of the lightning definitions and related resources:

> ```
> $ cat package.xml 
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
>     <types>
>         <members>*</members>
>         <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
>     </types>
>     <version>43.0</version>
> </Package>
> ```

Then find the files that contain the text string indicating the component in question, in this case, `c:myCmp`:

> ```
> $ grep c:myCmp -R .
> ./aura/myApp/myApp.app:    <c:myCmp />
> ```

Assuming that I haven't commented that section out, this would show that `myCmp` is being used in `myApp`.

I would imagine most of the IDE's out there would provide a similar type of search function.

---

Another option, if you know for sure the component is being referenced, would be to attempt to delete the component and look at the resulting errors.

For example, a deployment with a `destructiveChanges.xml` file that attempted to delete the `myCmp` lightning component failed because the component was being referenced by `myApp`:

[image: Deployment error]

And you don't need to use the metadata api for this trick either, an attempt to delete a referenced component in the developer console will also show the error:

[image]

Comment: Hi martin, Sorry for late reply i tried your first option i have **AuraDefinationBundle** information (like .js, .cmp etc).

Comment: @Shubham So far so good. Now you need a way to essentially ctrl+f through all of those files to find where the name of your component shows up. There are dedicated tools for doing this, and most IDE's should have that kind of text search feature, where you can search through all the files at once without having to open each and every one manually.

Comment: @matin I need more information of those pages contains my lightning component . I got referenced App information using your second option but I add my app in custom tab or directly used my lightning component in other pages like sobjects record page, edit page or in another pages layout using 'Edit Page' option of salesforce.

Comment: @Shubham Oh right, you will also need to retrieve the [`CustomTab`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_tab.htm) and [`FlexiPage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) metadata types.

Comment: Thanks @martin for sharing these links.

Comment: @Shubham no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Martin's answer, You can search for text in the meta-data files using the command prompt findstr

```
findstr /s SearchTerm "c:\*.flexipage"
```